# Moderator Button to Send a Post/Question to the TwitterBot

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, twitter

Would it be possible to add a button to the Mod menu for a Post or Question so that moderators can send it to the site's TwitterBot? I've seen previous posts about allowing Moderators more access to the accounts the TwitterBots use, and I'm not asking for that. Just a way to "nominate" a post for TwitterBot to post it.

Currently the TwitterBot has a reputation for selecting Questions that are "interesting" for all the wrong reasons. This would allow a moderator who sees a great Question the ability to push that question out, even if the Question doesn't currently meet the requirements for the bot to pick it up automatically.